# javascript button on clock

Tags: javascript, html

Now I have issue that only first clicked button works when pressing others post buttons after first clicked button, it just disappears and not loading comments,

Adding snipped to clarify issue. It's first time using this feature. Sorry for issues, may you can help me with that.

I'm using django as backend.

```js
var currentItems = 0;
            
function loadcomments(d) {
  var post = d.getAttribute("data-post");
  const elementList = document.querySelectorAll('#comment'+post);
  for (let i = currentItems; i < currentItems + 2; i++) {
    if (elementList[i]) {
      elementList[i].style.display = 'block';
    }  
  }
  currentItems += 2;
  if (currentItems >= elementList.length) {
    event.target.style.display = 'none';  
  }
}
```

```css
.comment {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='post'>
<div class='comment' id="comment1">
  11
</div>

<div class='comment' id="comment1">
  12
</div>

<div class='comment' id="comment1">
  13
</div>

<div class='comment' id="comment1">
  14
</div>

<div class='comment' id="comment1">
  15
</div>

<a class="loadmore" href="javascript:void(0)" 
onclick="loadcomments(this)" data-post="1">Load more</a>
</div>

<div class='post'>
<div class='comment' id="comment2">
  21
</div>

<div class='comment' id="comment2">
  22
</div>

<div class='comment' id="comment2">
  23
</div>



<a class="loadmore" href="javascript:void(0)" 
onclick="loadcomments(this)" data-post="2">Load more</a>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You've to declare and initialize `currentItems` outside of the function, currently the variable is initialized to `2` every time you click the button.

Comment: Thanks one of issue was that. I updated my main post, added snippet

Comment: Your markup is invalid. IDs must be unique or they don't identify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set special currentItems variable for each posts.

remove the global currentItems variable and Try

```
function loadcomments(d) {
    var post = d.getAttribute("data-post");
    var currentItems = d.getAttribute("data-currentItems") | 0;
    const elementList = document.querySelectorAll('#comment'+post);
    for (let i = currentItems; i < currentItems + 2; i++) {
        if (elementList[i]) {
            elementList[i].style.display = 'block';
        }  
    }
    currentItems += 2;
    d.setAttribute("data-currentItems", currentItems);
    if (currentItems >= elementList.length) {
        event.target.style.display = 'none';  
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to post a second answer? You probably should've updated your first one.

Answer (score 0):

As Teemu mentioned, "*You've to declare and initialize **currentItems** outside of the function*".

```js
var currentItems = 0;
            
function loadcomments(d) {
  var post = d.getAttribute("data-post");
  const elementList = document.querySelectorAll('#comment'+post);
  for (let i = currentItems; i < currentItems + 2; i++) {
    if (elementList[i]) {
      elementList[i].style.display = 'block';
    }  
  }
  currentItems += 2;
  if (currentItems >= elementList.length) {
    event.target.style.display = 'none';  
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="comment1">
  1
</div>

<div id="comment1">
  2
</div>

<div id="comment1">
  3
</div>

<div id="comment1">
  4
</div>

<div id="comment1">
  5
</div>

<a class="loadmore" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadcomments(this)" data-post="1">Load more</a>
```